# Can't click on dropdown on bootstrap navbar after something else on navbar has been clicked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a normal bootstrap navbar with some drop downs on it. When I click on a link in a drop down a modal box appears on screen, when I exit the modal box and then try to click on the drop down again on the navbar it won't work, an orange square border appears around the dropdown as if it can't get focus again or something. Any ideas why this could be happening?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">

<div class="navbar-inner" id="background">
    <a class="brand" href="@Url.Action("RssIndex", "Home")">
        <img src="~/Images/iconnewzy.png" alt="Newzy" ></a>

         <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-user"></i>
                            <label style="display: inline; cursor: pointer;" id="friendsId">Friends</label><b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" onclick="AddFriend()" style="width: 50%; white-space: nowrap; color: white; margin-left: 20px !important;">Add Friend</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" onclick="ViewFriends()" style="width: 50%; white-space: nowrap; color: white; margin-left: 20px !important;">View Friends</a>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    <b style="vertical-align: bottom !important; color: white">Hello, <a href="#" onclick="createManageModal()" style="color: white !important; vertical-align: bottom !important;">@User.Identity.Name</a>!</b>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Log off", "LogOff", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-mini btn-primary" })
         </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: The html code looks okay to me it could be the onclick events that you are calling on drop down menu.Have you tried debugging the code.Are there any errors in the developer tools for the browser that you are using?

Comment: Hi Sharma, thanks for response. I have debugged it in the javascript console, it didn't report any errors so I'm assuming the html is correct. I'm thinking it's something to do with my modal boxes. When I click out of them is where it begins to give me problems on the navbar. Now I am injecting actual views in the modal boxes. Could it be that? Maybe they need to be partial views?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I've found a workaround in [this article](http://mifsud.me/adding-dropdown-login-form-bootstraps-navbar/). Basically, you have to add this code to your page:

```js
$(function() {
  // Setup drop down menu
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

  // Fix input element click problem
  $('.dropdown input, .dropdown label').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```